# Upload file form MVC 3 opens a new tab

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I have an MVC 3 application which is a partial view (located in a view) which has a buttons that shows a div of uploading file.

The div is a form (which, as I mentioned, is part of the view), and as I submit the form, my controller code is uploading the file, and I want the div to be closed. It all happens, but in addition, a new tab is opened.


View code:

```
$("#btnUpload").click(function () {
    $('#UploadFile').submit();
    $("#UploadFileDiv").hide();
    });

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Maintenance", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "UploadFile", target = "_blank" }))
{

    <div id="UploadFileDiv" align="center" class="MyPopup" style="width: 500px; height: 250px; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 270px;">
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="myFile" id="btnFile" style="width:200px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <div align="center">
        <a class="Infobutton" id="btnUpload">Upload</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="Infobutton" id="btnCancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>

}
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile()
    {
            //Some code...

            string csvFileName = selectedMenu.ResourceFolder + "_" + selectedPage.ResourceFileName + ".csv";
            Request.Files["langFile"].SaveAs(csvPath);

            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            //return false;
            //return Json(false);
            return Json("File was uploaded");           
    }
```

> The "return" comments are what I already tried to do in order to prevent the appear of the new window

I tried to do the following in my javascript in order to prevent the new window:

```
function UploadFile_NEW() {
    $('#UploadFile').submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Maintenance")',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.Status);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (errorThrown == "Forbidden") {
                    alert("Forbidden access");
                } else {
                    alert('An error occurred please retry.');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $("#UploadFileDiv").hide();
}
```

It didn't work (form was not submitted)

Any ideas what can prevent the opening of new window in file upload?

***Note:*** I have a similar form for downloading file, and it works perfectly good

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete:

```
target = "_blank"
```

from

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Maintenance", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =     "multipart/form-data", id = "UploadFile", target = "_blank" }))
```

It should be:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Maintenance", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =     "multipart/form-data", id = "UploadFile"}))
```